# RegEx On MySQL Query To Do Left Join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have this table, named Prospects :

```
+---------+-------------+
| Name    | PhoneNumber |
+---------+-------------+
|John     | 08199999    |
|Viona    | 08332222    |
+---------+-------------+
```

on the other hand I have this table too, named SMSD :

```
+-----------------+---------------+
| Message         | PhoneNumber   |
+-----------------+---------------+
|Hello World!     | +628199999    |
|Hi World         | +628332222    |
+-----------------+---------------+
```

now I need to do LEFT JOIN to that both tables based on PhoneNumber : Prospects.PhoneNumber = SMSD.PhoneNumber while on the SMSD table phone number always had country code prefix.

thanks!

Comment: are the length of the values fixed? eg `+628199999` and `08199999 ` and also the pattern?

Comment: the only thing you can use as the pattern is the prefix. always started with +62 on SMSD table. the length of number are dynamic. for some GSM operator has 12 digits number, but other might have 11 or even 10 digits number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from Prospects
left join SMSD on substring(SMSD.PhoneNumber, 4) = substring(Prospects.PhoneNumber, 2)
```

(Not tested)

This should remove the country code prefix from the SMSD phone number and the leading zero from the Prospects phone number before performing the join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM prospects AS t1
JOIN SMSD AS t2
ON 
CONCAT(@prefix, SUBSTRING(t1.PhoneNumber, 2)) = t2.PhoneNumber
WHERE t1.PhoneNumber LIKE @prefix%
```